# Traversing an object after fetching it in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm fetching some data like so:

```
Vue.createApp({
data(){
    object: {},
},
...
mounted() {
    fetch("{SERVER_URL}/someurl.php?=getObject")
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((data) => {
                        this.object = data;
    }
...
}
```

Then, in the html I do the following

```
<div>{{object.parent.child}}</div>
```

Which returns

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'child')
```

While `{{translations.parent}}` correctly returns the parent object.

This is what the object looks like;

```
{
    "parent": {
        "child": "value",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

How can I correctly retrieve the `child`' `value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you fetch your data from server, your object doesn't have the parent attribute / key, but you are trying to access it. So, improve your code this way:

```
<div>{{object.parent?.child}}</div>
```

or this way, if you want to have more backwards compatible code:

```
<div>{{object.parent && object.parent.child}}</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I'll accept your answer asap. I understand your first suggestion, but what is happening in the second?

Comment: Second one works on principle of short evaluation of logical expressions. If object.parent returns undefined, it is evaluated as false, and JS will not try to evaluate right side, so it will not try to access child key in parent.